# How can i make this cursor to change the column values?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to sql and have no experince writing a cursor.
i have a column name `distance` in my table customer that has values like this

```
distance

5miles
3km
6miles
null
6km
```

i want to write a cursor that reads each columns numeric value for the distance column
and increase by 30% and multiply the whole figure with 0.62137 and replace the column value with the unit miles.
Could some body please help me with this. OR gimme an idea, i am in dire need to fix it.

Comment: do you have the values really like this? or are there two colums, one for distance (numeric) and one for the description (string)?

Comment: No i have values like this only in one column, string..

Comment: then first i would really rethink the database design if you have to calculate anything with those values.

Comment: database is like that only can not be changes, big project it is and existing for long..please help me with this...

Comment: Step away from the cursor. You **don't** want or need a cursor. But you've selected it because it seems familiar if you're coming at SQL programming from a procedural perspective.

Comment: no i have many database those holding values like this in the distance column, but now i need to change those values by directly executing a query on each database to adjust figure as mentioned above..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try it with a simple query:

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(distance, 'km' , '' ), 'miles', '')as float) * 1.3 * 0.62137 AS VARCHAR) + ' miles'
FROM customer
```

Here the strings are replaced and multiplied with your values, then it's casted back to string and conatenated with 'miles'.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear on exactly what calculations you're wanting to perform, or what you mean about replacing the column values with miles. But I'll show you a start:

```
--Your sample data
declare @t table (distance varchar(20) null)
insert into @t (distance) values
('5miles'),('3km'),('6miles'),(null),('6km')

--A possible update
; with Positioned as (
    select distance, PATINDEX('%[a-z]%',distance) as FirstLetter from @t
), Converted as (
    select distance,FirstLetter,CONVERT(int,SUBSTRING(distance,1,FirstLetter-1)) as Number from Positioned
)
update Converted set distance = CONVERT(varchar(20), Number * 0.6174) + 'miles ' + SUBSTRING(distance,FirstLetter,8000)

select * from @t
```

Which produces these results:

```
distance
--------------------
3.0870miles miles
1.8522miles km
3.7044miles miles
NULL
3.7044miles km
```

You'll note that, in the `UPDATE` statement, I have access to the numeric portion of the string, converted to an `int` (it could as easily be a `float`), and I also have access to the original units (if I want to do something based on those).

That's the best I can do at the moment - your question is quite unclear on exactly what transformation is to take place (you mention both an increase of 30% *and* a multiplication by 0.62137). So I went with:

> gimme an idea

Answer (score 1):

Improved [Obl Tobl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1855968/obl-tobl) answer a little:

```
UPDATE d    
SET 
    d.dist = CAST(CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(d1.dist, 'km', ''), 'miles', '') as FLOAT) * 1.3 * 0.62137 AS VARCHAR) + 'miles'
FROM distance d
INNER JOIN distance d1
    ON d.id = d1.id
```

Comment: why using a join? it's the same result if you update only on table d.